# Bonding two wifi interfaces using NetworkManager

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, networkmanager

I've got two different adapters connecting to the same Network with different speeds. I aim to join their bandwidth since my ISP's bandwidth is far more than what they both receive. I use NetworkManager on Manjaro distro.
My ISP gives 40Mbps for download bandwidth but when each of these adapters connect separately, one of them gets a connection speed of 14Mbps and the other 10Mpbs while downloading from a local device connected via Gigabit Ethernet to the router(Good too mention that I can download on 400Mbps via another device connected through Wifi in this situation).
Here's the process I went through.

```
nmcli con add type bond ifname bond0
nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 master bond0 ssid MYSSID
nmcli c modify bond-slave-wlan0 wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk MYPSK
nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlp1s0u1u4 master bond0 ssid MYSSID
nmcli c modify bond-slave-wlp1s0u1u4 wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk MYPSK
nmcli con up bond-slave-wlan0
nmcli c up bond-slave-wlp1s0u1u4
```

I can connect if either of the slaves are up, but when both of them are up I get `destination unreachable` on pinging `8.8.8.8`.

My router BTW gives IP to both adapters, which I think it shouldn't.

I've also tried using the following line instead of the first line too, but I got no changes.

```
nmcli con add type bond ifname bond0 bond.options "mode=802.3ad"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this? 802.3 is Ethernet... Unless you have two separate access points on different channels this will not increase bandwidth, 802.11 uses a shared medium.

Comment: I want to increase my bandwidth by joining them. Since they both get far more less than the speed that ISP gives to me.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I edited the question.

Comment: This is not bonding. Bonding turns two channels into one channel. But since you're trying to  connect to two different networks, one fast channel would be useless (what would the IP address for your end be?). You need to keep the two separate channels.

Comment: It's from the same ISP with the same external IP and ...   
But with two adapters. Can't I join their bandwidth ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question comes from a misunderstanding of how wifi works.

This will not increase speed. Wireless shares the same total bandwidth with all devices connected. Increasing the amount of clients connected will not increase the total speed of the routers wireless interface, infact more clients slightly degrade the total available bandwidth with overhead & management frames.

Upgrade your wireless cards & or router to a better standard if you require more bandwidth, the newer standards bond channels automatically (802.11-N/AC/AX)

Comment: Consider I've got an ethernet connection only, I'll then have a bandwidth of 37Mbps on average. Now consider I've got these to adapters separately connecting to the Wifi. I'll get 14Mbps on one of them and 10Mbps on the other one. I'd like to join these 2 bandwidths.

Answer (score 0):

> This will not increase speed. Wireless shares the same total bandwidth with all devices connected.

That's not always true: imagine two wireless adapters connected to the same* network on different bands (2.4 & 5 GHz).

(*) technically those are two different networks, sharing common SSID and L3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).